# How can I interaction to a contract by address from another contract?

Tags: solidity

I have to access methods of one contract from another contract body. How can I realize that using just a address of first contract?

```
contract KittyShelter{
    address KittenRegistry;   //Here, KittenRegistry - is another contract

    constructor(address _KittenRegistry) public{
        KittenRegistry = _KittenRegistry;
    }

    function storeKitty(uint256 catId, uint256 time) public{
        KittenRegistry;
    }
    function retrieveKitty(uint256 catId) public{

    }

}
```

Using address is a requirement

Comment: Inside each one of these methods, verify that `msg.sender` is equal to that other contract's address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In KittenRegistry contract first set address of KittyShelter contract. Then in the method, which you are calling from KittyShelter contract verify caller like: `require(msg.sender == KittyShelter)`